# Convert shapefile to .mdb file (Geomedia)

Tags: shapefile

I need to convert shapefiles (.shp) to .mdb file.

I tried to use GDAL libriary, but it supports only read operations on .mdb file, and It is why I cannot create a new .mdb source.

In the future I will need to automatize conversion by wrapping in .NET environment.

Do you have some experience in similar issues?

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We are not here to find software for you.

Comment: I am gonna wrap "this software" by C#, but it was easier to explain for me without describing circumstances, sorry :(